# What is the name of the Poker TV Show

Tags: texas-hold-em

There was a Poker TV Show where an amateur or "future pro" would be seated at the same table with big names (Daniel Negreanu etc.), given some chips, and he would keep everything he wins above a certain amount.

From time to time, there would be an interview with one of the pros where he would explain how he thought and why he played a hand a certain way.

I just want the name of the show.

Answer (score 3):

The Big Game. (PokerStars) extra characters